# Why AVD display nothing?

Tags: android, android-virtual-device

I have tried to use Android virtual devices but it don't want to work. AMD-V looks enabled but my CPU is maybe too old (AMD A8-3870 APU with Radeon(tm) HD Graphics). There is no error message and it looks like it doing something because my CPU load is 100% when a start it and the size of the disk is 7GB.

[A bugged screen and nothing else](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zZg1r.png)

Did someone have a clue of what is going wrong ?

I have tried on Windows and on Linux. A have tried to change the Setting named: Emulated Performance Graphics.